# Count the number of duplicate column pairs

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having difficulty with writing an expression for counting the number of duplicate column pairs.
For example, I have a table with two columns:

| BUYER | SELLER |
| --- | --- |
| ALEX | 1 |
| ALEX | 1 |
| ALEX | 1 |
| ALEX | 2 |
| ALEX | 2 |
| JOE | 1 |
| JOE | 3 |
| JOE | 3 |

I want to count the number of matching pairs for buyer and seller, and create a new column (count) based on the total number of matching pairs, as such:

| BUYER | SELLER | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ALEX | 1 | 3 |
| ALEX | 2 | 2 |
| JOE | 1 | 1 |
| JOE | 3 | 2 |

I know that the COUNT function is required to solve this, but am not sure how to implement it.

I would appreciate any help!
Thanks.

Comment: You want to aggregate your data so as to get one result row per buyer and seller. This translates to `GROUP BY buyer, seller`. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to `GROUP BY` the `buyer` and `seller` columns and then aggregate using the `COUNT` function:

```sql
SELECT buyer, seller, COUNT(*)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY buyer, seller
```

Comment: Would this be the same: SELECT buyer, seller, COUNT(DISTINCT buyer, seller) FROM   table_name

Comment: @mk6man No, you need the `GROUP BY` clause so that you have groups of distinct buyers/seller pairs but within each group the buyer and seller are identical for all the rows so counting `DISTINCT` buyers or seller within the group when the buyer/seller pair is identical within the group will only ever give you an output of 1. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zv8kfHzb)